# How to get the col and row value?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a little game with unity.
I have two classes (Board and Dot) and I'd like to get the column/row value of the Dot from the array "dotssss" when I click on a GameObject but it's too complicated for me.

I tried everything but it doesn't worked.

```csharp
using UnityEngine;

public class Board : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int width;
    public int height;
    public GameObject tilePrefab;
    public GameObject[] dots;
    private BackgroundTile[,] allTiles;
    public Dot[] dotssss;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start() {
        allTiles = new BackgroundTile[width, height];
        dotssss = new Dot[width*height];
        SetUp();
    }

    private void SetUp() {

        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
            {

                Vector2 tempPosition = new Vector2(i, j);
                GameObject backgroundTile = Instantiate(tilePrefab, tempPosition, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                backgroundTile.transform.parent = this.transform;
                backgroundTile.name = " ( " + i + ", " + j + " )";
                int dotToUse = 1;
                GameObject dot = Instantiate(dots[dotToUse], tempPosition, Quaternion.identity);
                dot.transform.parent = this.transform;
                dot.name = " ( " + i + ", " + j + " )";

                dotssss[k].column = i;
                dotssss[k].row = j;
                dotssss[k].nom = dot.name;
                k++;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

```csharp
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class Dot : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int column;
    public int row;
    public int type;
    public string nom;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    public Dot(int column, int row, int type, String name)
    {
        this.column = column;
        this.row = row;
        this.type = type;
        this.nom = name;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Debug.Log("TEST : " + this.GetComponent<Dot>().column + this.GetComponent<Dot>().row + ", " + this.GetComponent<Dot>().row);
        //Destroy(gameObject);
    }

}
```

Comment: Uh, `k = j*width + i`?

Comment: What do you expect `this.GetComponent<Dot>()` to do exactly? Juts use `column` and `row` directly. Is your `OnMouseDown` ever executing? What have you tried so far? Also, this isn't Java. Stop using `this.` all over the place.

Comment: @Draco18s Those aren't available in `OnMouseDown`.

Comment: @3Dave what exactly are you trying to achieve here. If you set in the dot when you make it, the values for column and row, it will be available in the OnMouseDown.... So what do you mean its not available - you dont need to get the component again, you are already in it.

Comment: I tried this code but I always have 0 in the Debug Log :

`dotssss[k] = new Dot(i, j, 1, dot.name);`

`Debug.Log("TEST : " + this.column + this.row + ", " + this.column);`

Please help !

Comment: Sorry, @3Dave I meant the op.. the whole point was the intterators wont be, but the column, and row he sets are.. and in the onmousedown there is the getcomponent which is irrelevant

Comment: @3Dave `i` and `j` aren't, but `column` and `row` are and hold the same values. It was the conversion from `x,y` coordinates to `index` coordinates (and back) is a long-time "do it on a whiteboard" programming interview question. Knowing the conversion is important. If the conversion isn't needed, then "What are you trying to do?" is the next question.

Comment: @Kevie You can't do `new Dot` because `Dot` is a MonoBehaviour derived class. It should throw an exception in Unity. Similarly MonoBehaviour derived classes ***must*** only have a zero-argument constructor.

Comment: @Draco18s It's not my question.

Comment: @3Dave I know its not. I can still tell you that "What are you trying to do?" is the next question.

Comment: Everything you've said, I said in my first comment. I'm not sure why you're `@`ing me about this stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to interact with `dotsss[k]` you need to make sure that it is referencing the right component.

```cs
private void SetUp()
{
    int k = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < height; j++)
        {

            Vector2 tempPosition = new Vector2(i, j);
            GameObject backgroundTile = Instantiate(tilePrefab, tempPosition, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            backgroundTile.transform.parent = this.transform;
            backgroundTile.name = " ( " + i + ", " + j + " )";
            int dotToUse = 1;
            GameObject dot = Instantiate(dots[dotToUse], tempPosition, Quaternion.identity);
            dot.transform.parent = this.transform;
            dot.name = " ( " + i + ", " + j + " )";

            // this is where you make your component reference
            dotssss[k] = dot.GetComponent<Dot>();
            dotssss[k].column = i;
            dotssss[k].row = j;
            dotssss[k].nom = dot.name;
            k++;
        }
    }
}
```

In addition a couple other things stand out:

1. You don't need to use

   ```
   this.GetComponent<Dot>()
   ```

   when you're inside *this* `Dot` already
2. In general you shouldn't use constructors (and `new`) for a class of type `MonoBehaviour` **at all**! The only allowed way of creating instances at runtime are either `Instantiate` via a prefab or `AddComponent` to an existing object. If you then need to pass in certain parameters do it e.g. in an `Initialize` method instead.
3. Despite the unnecessary work,

   ```
   Debug.Log("TEST : " + this.GetComponent<Dot>().column + this.GetComponent<Dot>().row + ", " + this.GetComponent<Dot>().row);
   ```

   should still be valid and do *something*. If it doesn't do anything, then OnMouseDown is not getting called.

It's worth noting that `OnMouseDown()` is  [only called for objects with GUIElements or Colliders](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html), so make sure you have a collider on the GameObject in question.

If you need to calculate "this Dot's" index in the dotsss array from inside the Dot rather than the Board, the Dot needs to know the board width, but then the math would be `index = column * width + row`.

Comment: Edited my answer to include something I missed before. Hope that does it!

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation, your answer is working great !